# updateLayout() causing parent container to scroll to top

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

calling updateLayout() is causing the parent container to "jump" to the top. Setting the viewconfig on the Ext.Container.container does not seem to help

```
viewConfig: {
    preserveScrollOnRefresh: true
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by Alexander, overriding `beforeLayout` and `afterLayout` for the parent container did the trick.

```
beforeLayout: function() {
    var me = this,
        scroller = me.getScrollable();
    me.callParent(arguments);
    if (scroller) {
        me.savedScrollPos = scroller.getPosition();
    }
},
afterLayout: function() {
    var me = this,
        scroller = me.getScrollable();
    me.callParent(arguments);
    if (scroller && me.savedScrollPos) {
        scroller.scrollTo(me.savedScrollPos);
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. Works well. The only thing is I was trying to do the same on 6.0.2 Containers and I had to use beforeadd instead of beforeLayout because it was missing. Why do you do the me.callParent(args) anyways?

Answer (score 4):

`updateLayout` is not the same as `refresh`, and `preserveScrollOnRefresh` only preserves scroll on `refresh`. You could look into ExtJS code how they did it (they don't really "preserve" scroll, they store the scroll position and scroll back to the correct position after refresh) and implement the same for updateLayout.

Answer (score 1):

To cover more options for anyone having similar problems:

**Changing the layout**

As mentioned in question [Avoid Ext.form validation scrolling to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083971/avoid-ext-form-validation-scrolling-to-top), sometimes just changing the [`layout`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-cfg-layout) can do the trick.

For example form in ExtJS 4.x had `anchor` layout specified by default (ExtJS 6 has `vbox`), which caused the form to scroll to top on form field validation, if you change the layout to `vbox`, it does not scroll to top.

**Suspending layout**

If you have a component, that does not need to update the layout with its change, you can use the [`suspendLayout`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.container.Container.html#cfg-suspendLayout) configuration.